# Angular module is executed twice only when testing

Tags: angularjs, testing, mocking, phantomjs

My angular application is working ok when ran normally, but seems to be executed twice when I'm doing unit tests (using Karma & PhantomJS)

It is instanciated as follows:

### bootstrap.js

```
require('./app.js');

var app = document.URL.indexOf( 'http://' ) === -1 && document.URL.indexOf( 'https://' ) === -1;

if ( app ) {
    console.log('App running on a mobile device');
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['esme']);
    });
} else {
    console.log("App running in a browser");
    angular.element(document).ready(function() {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['esme']);
    });
}
```

### app.js

```
var esme = angular.module('esme', ['ui.router', 'ngAnimate', 'ngTouch', 'DataStore', 'angular-carousel', 'SessionParams', 'hmTouchEvents']);

esme.run(['$location', '$rootScope', '$state', 'NotificationManager', function($location, $rootScope, $state, NotificationManager) {
    console.log('run');

    NotificationManager.init();

    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function (event, current, previous) {
        if($state.current.data)
            $rootScope.title = $state.current.data.title;
    });
}]);
```

### Test.js

```
describe('TestController', function() {
    var $controller;
    var $rootScope;

    beforeEach(module('esme'));

    beforeEach(module(function($urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.deferIntercept();
    }));

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _$rootScope_){
        // The injector unwraps the underscores (_) from around the parameter names when matching
        $controller = _$controller_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_.$new();
    }));

    describe('$scope.cheer', function() {
        var $scope, controller;

        beforeEach(function() {
            $scope = $rootScope;
            controller = $controller('Main', { $scope: $scope });
        });

        describe("#hello()", function(){
            it('ensures hello is correct', function() {
                $scope.test.should.equal('test');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

The output of a browser console is the following:

> "App running in a browser"
>
> "config"
>
> "run"

But the output of the unit test is the following:

> INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.31 server started at http://localhost:9876/
>
> [ .. Karma / PhantomJS stuff .. ]
>
> LOG: 'App running in a browser'
>
> WARN [web-server]: 404: /views/Main/Login.html
>
> LOG: 'config'
>
> LOG:'run'
>
> LOG: 'config'
>
> LOG: 'run'
>
> PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7): Executed 1 of 1 SUCCESS (0.007 secs / 0.001 secs)
>
> WARN [web-server]: 404: /views/Main/Login.html
>
> [17:16:14] Finished 'test:unit' after 5.31 s

I'm still learning how to mock an angular application so I strongly believe that I made some obvious mistakes in the test file. Can you please help me find them and explain why did this behavior happened ?

The only clue I may have for now comes from [Angular's doc](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/ce669edfa14dc7eb7c389d2f82c9c98399a9009b/docs/content/guide/module.ngdoc), *should I declare a module only for running the app ?*:

> Run blocks - get executed after the injector is created and are used to kickstart the application. Only instances and constants can be
>   injected into run blocks. This is to prevent further system
>   configuration during application run time.
>
> Run blocks are the closest thing in Angular to the main method. A run block is the code which needs to run to kickstart the application.
>   It is executed after all of the service have been configured and the
>   injector has been created. Run blocks typically contain code which is
>   hard to unit-test, and for this reason should be declared in isolated
>   modules, so that they can be ignored in the unit-tests.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a good night, the answer was straightforward...

Because I was doing manual bootstrapping, in my karma.conf file, I simple excluded the file where the it was done.

### Karma.conf

```
files: [
    'lib/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
    'src/js/**/*.js',
    'test/test.js'
],

// list of files to exclude
exclude: [
    'src/js/bootstrap.js'
],
```